# Joint transformation of a gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I have a question regarding the transformation of a gamma distribution. I think I solved the problem, but I am not sure whether it is correct.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and Gamma distributed with paramters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$, i.e. $f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}$ and $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha -1}e^{-x}dx$

Define $R=\frac{X}{X+Y}, T=X+Y$. What is the joint density of $T$ and $R$?

I would say the inverse of $r$ and $t$ are given by:
$x=rt$ and $y=t(1-r)$. The Jacobian $J(r,t)=|t|$.

Following the joint transformation theorem, $f_{RT}(r,t)=f_{XY}(x(r,t),y(r,t))\cdot |J(r,t)|$

Because of independence, $=f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x) \cdot f_{Y}(y)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}\cdot \frac{\lambda^\alpha\cdot y^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}$

Hence, $f_{RT}(r,t)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha\cdot rt^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda rt}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}\cdot \frac{\lambda^\alpha\cdot t(1-r)^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda t(1-r)}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}t$

I am not sure how the Gamma-function, if at all, should transform. Could anyone give me a hint here?

Comment: Continuing would have given you that $$f_{R,T}(r,t)=\lambda^{2\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)^{-2}r^{\alpha-1}(1-r)^{\alpha-1}{\mathbf 1}_{0<r<1}t^{2\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda t}\mathbf 1_{t>0},$$ which you could have compared to the product of the known [gamma density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) $$\Gamma(2\alpha)^{-1}\lambda^{2\alpha}t^{2\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda t}\mathbf 1_{t>0}$$ and of the known [beta density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) $$\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\alpha)^{-1}r^{\alpha-1}(1-r)^{\alpha-1}\mathbf 1_{0<r<1}.$$ Can you conclude from these remarks?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in that case I would conclude that the $f_{R,T}(r,t)$ found was indeed the joint density function and that they are both independent, with $r $~$ Gamma(2\alpha, \lambda)$. Is that the correct conclusion?

Comment: I can't change my comment, but it should have been $t$~$Gamma(2\alpha,\lambda)$.